# jQuery Validation Method - validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, idealforms

Having problem to disable validation in idealforms, I would like to have following fields not being validated

postcode3, memo2, previous_year, previous_month

until value in current_year is less then 3

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#current_year').on("input", function() {
    var dInput = this.value;
    console.log(dInput);
    $('#current_year').text(dInput);

    $('form.idealforms').idealforms('addRules', {
        'postcode3': ( parseInt( $('#current_year').val() ) < 3) ? 'required' : '',
    });
});



      $('form.idealforms').idealforms({

      silentLoad: false,    

      rules: {
        'postcode2': 'required',
        'memo1': 'required',
        'current_year': 'required',
        'current_month': 'required',
      },


      onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#invalid')
          .show()
          .toggleClass('valid', ! invalid)
          .text(invalid ? (invalid +' invalid fields') : 'All good!');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your code is correct I think the issue is that `val()` returns a `string` and not a `number`. You'll need to write your expressions like so

```
( parseInt( $('#current_year').val() ) < 3 ) : 'required' : '';
```

or compare val() to the string value of the number.

```
( $('#current_year').val() < '3' ) : 'required' : '';
```

**Edit**

There is a second issue in that once your rules are declared, nothing in your code changes the rules. So if onload `$('#current_year').val()` is less then 3, your fields will always be required.

According to the [plugin docs](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms#adding-rules) you can add rules after initializing the plugin like so

```
$('form').idealforms('addRules', {
  'comments': 'required minmax:50:200'
});
```

So you might be able to do use this to update the rules like so.

```
$('#current_year').on("input", function() {

    $('form.idealforms').idealforms('addRules', {
        'postcode3': ( parseInt( $('#current_year').val() ) < 3) ? 'required' : '',
    });

});
```

Comment: but I am not getting $('#current_year').val() in the rules, I am getting that only above when on input function (insert value to input field) and looks like its not passed to rules.

Comment: and when I load the page its always required and there is no value for current_year

Comment: That's because once your rules are declared they won't change. Editing my answer with more code.

Comment: with this new solution after value is inserted in current_year, I am landing on step 1, validation is on step 4. Also when switched for step 4 I cannot see any difference with validation.

Comment: what do you mean by step 1 and step 4?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: its to much mate, file got 3000 lines. I am using https://code.google.com/p/idealforms/

Comment: You can link to ideal forms and create a minimal test case.

Comment: So new when on step 2 I enter No. of Years: in first section and its less then 3 I would like 2nd address fields required, then again  if I enter previous_year in the 2nd address I would like fields from address 3 be required. otherwise only 1st address fields are required